# Pylons Authkit with Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pylons

I am planning to use mongodb with pylons.
I was wondering whether authkit has support with mongodb.

If there aren't can someone please tell me what are my options?

Thax

Answer (score 1):

doubt it, AuthKit hasn't been updated in [13 months](https://hg.3aims.com/public/AuthKit/summary)

I would suggest [repoze.who](http://docs.repoze.org/who/1.0/) and write your own identifier plugin to hit your user schema from mongo. Or if you want, the next version of pylons will run on top of [pyramid](http://docs.pylonshq.com/pyramid/dev/index.html) which has it's own [authentication/authorization](http://docs.pylonshq.com/pyramid/dev/narr/security.html) that doesn't take much to extend at all.